# How to calculate growth rate of this function: T(n) = 2T(n^(1/2)) + 2(n^(1/2))

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I need to calculate the growth rate of this function for my homework:

```
T(n) = 2T( n^(1/2) ) + 2( n^(1/2) )
```

To put it another way:

```
T(n) = 2T( sqrt(n) ) + 2( sqrt(n) )
```

Changing variables might help (something like `n = 2^m`)

The answer I found is `log(n)*log(log(n))`, but I know that is incorrect.

Comment: Can you show *how* you found that answer?

Answer (score 1):

`n = 2^m` is indeed the correct variable substitution to use. Define a function `S(m)`:

```
S(m) = T(n) = T(2^m)

T(sqrt(n)) = T(2^[m/2]) = S(m/2)

S(m) = 2S(m/2) + 2^[m/2+1]
```

Expansion:

```
S(m) =  4*S(m/4)  + 2*2^[m/4+1]  + 2^[m/2+1]
     =  8*S(m/8)  + 4*2^[m/8+1]  + 2^[m/4+2] + 2^[m/2+1]
     = 16*S(m/16) + 8*2^[m/16+1] + 2^[m/8+3] + 2^[m/4+2] + 2^[m/2+1]
     = ...
```

`2^[m/2]` will dominate all of the other terms, so:

```
S(m) = O(2^[m/2])

*********************
*                   *
* T(n) = O(sqrt(n)) *
*                   *
*********************
```

The above can also be derived using the [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) (Case 3).